# How can I dim semicolons and curly braces in VS Code for all languages?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to dim/hide semicolons and curly braces in VS Code? (I want to do this for all languages).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)

Add this to your settings:

```json
"highlight.regexes": {
  "(;|\\{|\\})": [
    { "color": "#ffffff" }
  ]
}
```

Instead of `#ffffff` choose a color that is equal or close to the editor background color.

I had created a Pull Request to make the settings Theme specific but it is not merged.

Maybe you have to change the setting `highlight.maxMatches` to get all changed.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think such a thing exists (at least at the time of this writing).

I looked through the generic customization points in `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` > `rules` and in `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` and didn't see anything in particular for braces, semicolons, or punctuation.

I think you'll have to do this on a per-language basis, which is the usual route of using the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command and getting scopes and writing colour customizations for each one.